# json4s, how to deserialize json with FullTypeHints w/o explicitly setting TypeHints

Tags: scala, serialization, deserialization, json4s

I do specify FullTypeHints before deserialization

```scala
 def serialize(definition: Definition): String = {
    val hints = definition.tasks.map(_.getClass).groupBy(_.getName).values.map(_.head).toList
    implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(FullTypeHints(hints))
    writePretty(definition)
  }
```

It produces json with type hints, great!

```
{
  "name": "My definition",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "jsonClass": "com.soft.RootTask",
      "name": "Root"
    }
  ]
}
```

Deserialization doesn't work, it ignores "jsonClass" field with type hint

```scala
  def deserialize(jsonString: String): Definition = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats.withTypeHintFieldName("jsonClass")
    read[Definition](jsonString)
  }
```

Why should I repeat typeHints using `Serialization.formats(FullTypeHints(hints))` for deserialization if hints are in json string?

Can `json4s` infer them from json?

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deserialiser is not ignoring the type hint field name, it just does not have anything to map it with. This is where the hints come in. Thus, you have to declare and assign your hints list object once again and pass it to the DefaultFormats object either by using the withHints method or by overriding the value when creating a new instance of DefaultFormats. Here's an example using the latter approach.

```
val hints = definition.tasks.map(_.getClass).groupBy(_.getName).values.map(_.head).toList
implicit val formats: Formats = new DefaultFormats {
    outer =>
        override val typeHintFieldName = "jsonClass"
        override val typeHints = hints
}
```

Comment: Agree, it works with explicit settting. I'm surprised that I can't set 'typeHintFieldName' and 'FullTypeHints' to deserializer. It's more than enough to map json to concrete class instances

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way since I have contract:

- `withTypeHintFieldName` is known in advance
- `withTypeHintFieldName` contains fully qualified class name and it's always case class

```scala
def deserialize(jsonString: String): Definition = {
    import org.json4s._
    import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
    import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
    val json = parse(jsonString)
    val classNames: List[String] = (json \\ $$definitionTypes$$ \\ classOf[JString])
    val hints: List[Class[_]] = classNames.map(clz => Try(Class.forName(clz)).getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException(s"Can't get class for $clz")))

    implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(FullTypeHints(hints)).withTypeHintFieldName($$definitionTypes$$)
    read[Definition](jsonString)
```